# Calling protected ctor of inheriting class from within static template method of base class fails

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, protected

I have a component class that defines a static template method of how a `Component` should be created in general:

```
class Component {
protected:
    uint32_t id;

    Component(uint32_t id) :
            id(id) {
    }

    template<typename T, uint32_t C>
    static T* createComponent() {
        // content here not relevant
        return new T(someParameter);
    }

};
```

Then there is an implementation, for example a `Button`. The constructor of this class should not be used directly, instead there is a static method that calls the `Component::createComponent` template function.

```
class Button: public Component {
protected:
    Button(uint32_t id) :
            Component(id) {
    }
public:
    static Button* create();
};
```

The implementation looks like this, passing the type to instantiate and a constant thats used in creation:

```
Button* Button::create() {
    return createComponent<Button, UI_COMPONENT_BUTTON>();
}
```

Now the problem is, that the compiler complains with *"error: 'Button::Button(uint32_t)' is protected"*. For my understanding, this constructor call should be OK as `Button` extends `Component`, but this seems to be a problem here.

How can I solve this?

Comment: The complexity of your title is cracking me up but this is a good question.

Comment: I couldn't imagine an easier one that describes the basic problem :D

Comment: Well, your constructor doesn't do anything that the 'Create' method couldn't, so just don't use any Ctor?

Comment: The problem is that there is also a `Window` class that does not use the `createComponent` function, though I still wanted to force it to pass the id to the constructor. But yes, you are right, I can just add that logic to the template function. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your `create()` function won't be able to deal with further inherited classes you can take advantage of this and *not* create a `Button` but, instead, a generic derived, protected, derived class which would have access to your `protected` constructor:

```
class Component {
    uint32_t id;
    template <typename T>
    struct Concrete: T {
        Concrete(uint32_t id): T(id) {}
    };
protected:
    Component(uint32_t id) :
        id(id) {
    }

    template<typename T, uint32_t C>
    static T* createComponent() {
        // content here not relevant
        return new Concrete<T>(C);
    }
};

class Button:
    public Component {
protected:
    Button(uint32_t id): Component(id) {}
public:
    static Button* create() {
         return createComponent<Button, UI_COMPONENT_BUTTON>();
    }
};
```

Comment: Yes, `Base::createComponent()` when called with a `ConcreteButton<T>`, indeed, das return a `Concrete<Button>*`. However. The user calls `Button::create()` which returns a base class thereof: `Button*`.

Comment: Thinking a bit harder about it, `Base::createComponent()` could actually use `Button` and internally just create a `ConcreteButton<T>` - this way the derived classes won't even need to know about this auxiliary class and it can be private in `Base`! I shall update the code correspondingly.

Comment: You could also instantiate `Concrete<T>` within the `createComponent` to make it even easier :)

Comment: Comment race condition :D Nice work, wouldn't have figured that out :)

Answer (score 2):

Access specifier of Button constructor is protected that means it can only be accessed by classes derived from Button. If you want your code to work then you have to make that constructor public.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the inheritance would still work upwards. Found another solution that works too: adding `friend class Component;` to the class body of the `Button`.

Comment: Correct. `protected` does not grant access to base classes, only to derived classes...

Comment: @maxdev: Just for the record: you absolutely do **NOT** have to make the constructor `public` and based on what you write you probably don't want to. Although the access right do not work upwards, you can just use a simple delegation through a derived class controlled by the base to deal with the `protected` constructor (see, e.g., my answer).

Answer (score 0):

"Button" extends "Component", so "Button" can access protected members of "Component", but "Component" does not know about "Button", and so cannot access it's protected members.

Comment: *does not know about* is a little vague, I could just make the class know it.